# Lazy regex that starts match at last match not ends at first

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract data from semi structured text, it is an email composed of tab delimited tables. Users have entered time stamp on top of each table and within the table they list security identifiers that I am looking for.

The goal is to extract `correctsecurity` and the time stamp on top of the table that `correctsecurity` is located at.

For example...

```
10:00 AM
not it
not it

9:00 AM
not it
correctsecurity
```

..is supposed to return  `9:00 AM correctsecurity`. However my current regex is returning `10:00 AM correctsecurity`, meaning right item, but not the right time.

Here is my regex so far:

`((1[0-2]|[0-9]):[0-5][0-9](\s?(AM|PM))?)(?:(.*\n)+)(correctsecurity)`

Note that the last part `correctsecurity` is being created dynamically based on other criteria so even if I were to provide the actual item in this question it would do little help(because it is one of many), for simplicity sake please assume that `correctsecurity` is exactly the item I am looking for.

Lastly I am doing this in VBA so maybe solving this whole problem is easier without using a long regex, so feel free proposed non regex solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the main problem simply change the central section of your regex to not accept empty lines:

> `.*\n` -> `.+\n`

Then add a newline anchor `\n` before the central section to avoid the skip of the `AM|PM` section:

So your regex will be:

[`((1[0-2]|[0-9]):[0-5][0-9](\s?(AM|PM))?)\n(?:(.+\n)+)(correctsecurity)`](https://regex101.com/r/eI7uN4/1)

```
                                        ^      ^
Changes --------------------------------|------|
```

---

**Optional Optimization**
You may remove many unneeded groups and add a generic multi-os regex for the newline `(?:\r\n?|\n)`:

[`((?:1[0-2]|[0-9]):[0-5][0-9](?: [AP]M)?)(?:\r\n?|\n)(?:[^\r\n]+(?:\r\n?|\n))+(correctsecurity)`](https://regex101.com/r/hQ7nX6/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with negative lookahead :

```
a((?!a).)*correctsecurity
```

Where a is the pattern that you want to start the match at and don't want to encouter in the middle of the match.

Applied to your specif needs :

```
\d*:\d* [AP]M((?!\d*:\d* [AP]M).)*correctsecurity
```

Don't forget to let the dot match line breaks.

I assume VBA uses thee VBScript regex dialect which requires the following modification:

```
\d*:\d* [AP]M((?!\d*:\d* [AP]M)[\s\S])*correctsecurity
```